# Laravel Transaction Not Working On Collection each() method

Tags: php, excel, laravel, postgresql, docker-compose

I Have a class that perform looping through excel file, and insert every valid rows like this.

```
<?php

namespace App\Services\Factory\PayrollUpload\Impl;
use App\Helpers\Api\Facades\HrisOutbound;
use App\Helpers\Constants\ExcelFile;
use App\Models\Allowance;
use App\Models\Deduction;
use App\Models\Salary;
use App\Repository\Facades\AllowanceRepository;
use App\Repository\Facades\DeductionRepository;
use App\Repository\Facades\PeriodRepository;
use App\Repository\Facades\SalaryRepository;
use App\Services\Factory\PayrollUpload\Base\PayrollUploadBase;
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Spatie\SimpleExcel\SimpleExcelReader;
use Spatie\SimpleExcel\SimpleExcelWriter;

class EPayrollUpload implements PayrollUploadBase
{

    /**
     * Method process file to table
     *
     * @param $file $file xlsx
     * @param $companyCode $companyCode
     * @param $month $month
     * @param $year $year
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function process(UploadedFile $file, $companyCode, $month, $year)
    {
        $result = [];
        $failedRows = [];
        $success = 0;
        $failed = 0;
        /** @var SimpleExcelReader $excelFile */
        $excelFile = SimpleExcelReader::create($file, 'xlsx');
        // Count Total Rows
        $totalRows = $excelFile->getRows()->count();
        $lowerCaseHeaders = array_map('strtolower', SimpleExcelReader::create($file, 'xlsx')->getHeaders());

        DB::beginTransaction();

        // Loop Through Excel File
        $excelFile
                  ->useHeaders($lowerCaseHeaders)
                  ->getRows()
                  ->each(function ($row, $index) use ($companyCode, $month, $year, $success, $failed, $failedRows)
                  {
                    try
                    {
                        // Get Employee Detail
                        $employeeDetail = HrisOutbound::getEmployeeDetail($row["nik"], $companyCode);
                        // Grouping Allowances
                        $allowances = self::getValuesByKeys($row, ExcelFile::ETHOS_ALLOWANCES);
                        // Grouping Deductions
                        $deductions = self::getValuesByKeys($row, ExcelFile::ETHOS_DEDUCTIONS);
                        // Grouping Tax
                        // Find base salary
                        $baseSalary = self::sumValuesByKeys($row, ["total gaji proporsional"]);
                        // Find Total Earning
                        $totalEarning = self::sumValuesByKeys($row, ["thp"]);
                        $totalAllowances = self::sumValuesByKeys($row, ExcelFile::ETHOS_ALLOWANCES);
                        $totalDeduction = self::sumValuesByKeys($row, ExcelFile::ETHOS_DEDUCTIONS);

                        // Find Or Create Period
                        DB::beginTransaction();

                        $period = PeriodRepository::getOrCreate($companyCode, $month, $year);

                        // Save to table salaries
                        $salary = new Salary();
                        $salary->employee_id = $employeeDetail["data"]["employee"]["id"];
                        $salary->company_id = $employeeDetail["data"]["employee"]["company_id"];
                        $salary->company_code = $companyCode;
                        $salary->base_salary = $baseSalary;
                        $salary->net_salary = $totalEarning;
                        $salary->deductions = $totalDeduction;
                        $salary->allowances = $totalAllowances;
                        $salary->period_id = $period->period_id;

                        $salary->save();

                        foreach($allowances as $key => $allowance)
                        {
                            $allow = new Allowance();
                            $allow->salary_id = $salary->salary_id;
                            $allow->allowance_name = $key;
                            $allow->amount = $allowance;
                            $allow->save();
                        }

                        foreach ($deductions as $key => $deduction)
                        {
                            $deduct = new Deduction();
                            $deduct->salary_id = $salary->salary_id;
                            $deduct->deduction_name = $key;
                            $deduct->amount = $deduction;
                            $deduct->save();
                        }

                        // Increment success count
                        $success++;

                        DB::commit();
                    }
                    catch (\Throwable $th)
                    {
                        // Add failed to collection failed
                        DB::rollBack();
                        $row["error"] = $th->getMessage();
                        $failedRows[] = $row;
                        $failed++;
                    }
                  });

        // If not empty store failed collection as excel file in S3
        // if(!empty($failedRows))
        // {
        //     /** @var SimpleExcelWriter $excel */
        //     $excel = SimpleExcelWriter::create($file->getFilename()."_result.xlsx");
        //     $excel->addRows($failedRows);

        //     Storage::disk('s3')->put('folder/example.xlsx', $excel->__destruct());
        // }

        $result["company_code"] = $companyCode;
        $result["month"] = $month;
        $result["year"] = $year;
        $result["total_row"] = $totalRows;
        $result["success_row"] = $success;
        $result["failed_row"] = $failed;
        // $result["file_result_url"] = Storage::disk('s3')->url('folder/example.xlsx');

        return $result;
    }


    /**
     * Method getValuesByKeys
     *
     * @param array $data array to proceed
     * @param array $keysToRetrieve keys to filter
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function getValuesByKeys(array $data, array $keysToRetrieve)
    {
        $values = [];

        foreach ($keysToRetrieve as $key)
        {
            $values[$key] = Arr::get($data, $key);
        }

        return $values;
    }

    private function sumValuesByKeys(array $data, array $keysToRetrieve)
    {
        $sum = 0;

        foreach ($keysToRetrieve as $key)
        {
            $value = Arr::get($data, $key);

            if (is_numeric($value))
            {
                $sum += $value;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new \InvalidArgumentException("KEY_'{$key}'IS_NOT_NUMERIC");
            }
        }

        return $sum;
    }
}
```

And i have a test that check if the code is running a looping and make sure the data was inserted to db, the test was passed, but if i running this code in the development mode, and tryin to make the request to the API upload, it's not perform a DB transaction, and no error occured, data in table salaries is empty as well as data in table periods

my code was running on Laravel (Container) who are connected to postgresql database inside container too. this is my docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  http:
    image: nginx:1.20
    ports:
      - '8881:80'
    volumes:
      - './:/app/'
      - './docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf'
    depends_on:
      - php
    networks:
      - payroll_network
  php:
    build:
      context: ./docker/php/
      args:
        WWWUSER: 'laravel'
        WWWUID: '1000'
    volumes:
      - '.:/app/'
    # extra_hosts:
    #   - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
    networks:
      - payroll_network
    depends_on:
      - pgsql
    links:
      - pgsql
      - mailhog
      - localstack
#   node:
#     image: node:16
#     volumes:
#         - './:/app/'
#     working_dir: '/app/'
  pgsql:
    container_name: 'payroll_db'
    image: postgres:14
    ports:
      - '${DB_PORT:-5432}:5432'
    environment:
      PGPASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD:-secret}'
      POSTGRES_DB: '${DB_DATABASE:-laravel}'
      POSTGRES_USER: '${DB_USERNAME:-laravel}'
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD:-secret}'
      PGDATA: '/data/postgres'
    volumes:
      - 'pgsql:/data/postgres'
    networks:
      - payroll_network
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready", "-q", "-d", "${DB_DATABASE:-laravel}", "-U", "${DB_USERNAME:-laravel}" ]
  mailhog:
    image: 'mailhog/mailhog:latest'
    ports:
      - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_PORT:-1025}:1025'
      - '${FORWARD_MAILHOG_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025'
    networks:
      - payroll_network

  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack
    environment:
      - SERVICES=s3
      - DEFAULT_REGION=${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
    ports:
      - "4566:4566"  # Port untuk LocalStack S3
    networks:
      - payroll_network

networks:
  payroll_network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  pgsql:
```

is there something i miss? because db transaction not working properly and there is no exception occured, is there something with the collection each() method or something?

Answer (score 0):

So i figure out about the problem that persist in my code, there is an throwable thrown by the http request in HrisOutbound::getEmployeeDetail(), this code is not handle by catch exception, its should be added more catch with Throwable, so i change my code like this

```
// Loop Through Excel File
        $excelFile
                  ->useHeaders($lowerCaseHeaders)
                  ->getRows()
                  ->each(function ($row) use ($companyCode, $month, $year, &$success, &$failed, &$failedRows)
                  {
                    try
                    {
                        // Get Employee Detail
                        $employeeDetail = HrisOutbound::getEmployeeDetail($row["nik"], $companyCode);
                        // Grouping Allowances
                        $allowances = self::getValuesByKeys($row, ExcelFile::ETHOS_ALLOWANCES);
                        // Grouping Deductions
                        $deductions = self::getValuesByKeys($row, ExcelFile::ETHOS_DEDUCTIONS);
                        // Grouping Tax
                        // Find base salary
                        $baseSalary = self::sumValuesByKeys($row, ["total gaji proporsional"]);
                        // Find Total Earning
                        $totalEarning = self::sumValuesByKeys($row, ["thp"]);
                        $totalAllowances = self::sumValuesByKeys($row, ExcelFile::ETHOS_ALLOWANCES);
                        $totalDeduction = self::sumValuesByKeys($row, ExcelFile::ETHOS_DEDUCTIONS);

                        // Find Or Create Period
                        DB::beginTransaction();

                        $period = PeriodRepository::getOrCreate($companyCode, $month, $year);

                        // Save to table salaries
                        $salary = new Salary();
                        $salary->employee_id = $employeeDetail["data"]["employee"]["id"];
                        $salary->company_id = $employeeDetail["data"]["employee"]["company_id"];
                        $salary->company_code = $companyCode;
                        $salary->base_salary = $baseSalary;
                        $salary->net_salary = $totalEarning;
                        $salary->deductions = $totalDeduction;
                        $salary->allowances = $totalAllowances;
                        $salary->period_id = $period->period_id;

                        $salary->save();

                        foreach($allowances as $key => $allowance)
                        {
                            $allow = new Allowance();
                            $allow->salary_id = $salary->salary_id;
                            $allow->allowance_name = $key;
                            $allow->amount = $allowance;
                            $allow->save();
                        }

                        foreach ($deductions as $key => $deduction)
                        {
                            $deduct = new Deduction();
                            $deduct->salary_id = $salary->salary_id;
                            $deduct->deduction_name = $key;
                            $deduct->amount = $deduction;
                            $deduct->save();
                        }

                        // Increment success count
                        $success++;

                        DB::commit();
                    }
                    catch(\Throwable $th)
                    {
                        // Add failed to collection failed
                        DB::rollBack();
                        $row["error"] = $th->getMessage();
                        $failedRows[] = $row;
                        $failed++;
                    }
                    catch(\Exception $e)
                    {
                        // Add failed to collection failed
                        DB::rollBack();
                        $row["error"] = $e->getMessage();
                        $failedRows[] = $row;
                        $failed++;
                    }
                  });
```